# How do I replace and remove character at the same time in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a bunch of product code that I wish to shorten and add some character all at the same time. would that be possible?

e.g.:
`811C994/2082I`
`811C1000/CT220`

I would like to remove the the first 3 character of the product code (i.e. 811) and all character after "/" (inclusive of "/" as well)

e.g.:
`811C994/2082I > C994`
`811C1000/CT220 -> C1000`

after which I would like to add a bunch of "0" after the first character to create a 7 character product code

e.g.:
`C994 -> C000994`
`C1000 -> C001000`

Comment: only with Excel formula or vba code allowed ?

Comment: both excel and vba code allow. which ever method to produce the fastest results

Comment: Will that letter will always be `C` and at 4th position?

Comment: yes it remains at the 4th position

Answer (score 0):

Start of with the following in cell b1

```
=Right(a1,len(a1)-3)
```

That removes the left 3 characters.

Then in c1

```
=Left(b1, search ("/",b1))
```

That removes everything to the right of the "/" character.

Or it might be;

```
=Left(b1, search ("/",b1)-1)
```

And if you don't want the 2 columns replace each 'b1' in the second formula with the formula I recommended for the cell b1

Then in D1 enter

```
 = left(C1,1)&rept('0',7-len(c1))& right (C1,len(C1)-1)
```

To repeat 0 starting atfter the first letter of the code enough to bring the total number of characters to 7.

Comment: yup i know these 2 methods to remove and shorten the product code. i'm stuck with the last bit which is the tricky part for me which is to add zeros after the 1st character to produce a 7 character product code :(

Comment: Oops. Updated with that bit too now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in cell `A2`:

`=MID(A2,4,1)&TEXT(MID(LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2,1)-1),5,99),"000000")`

Copy down as much as you need and if it is always C then

`="C"&TEXT(MID(LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2,1)-1),5,99),"000000")`

can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

> =MID(A1,4,1)&TEXT(MID(A1,5,FIND("/",A1,5)-5), "0000000")